# Find all combinations of -1 and 1 for a given sum

Tags: matlab, sieve-of-eratosthenes

How can I find all the combinations  that added provide a given sum given the fact that the possible values can be `1` or `-1`

I am given an array of coefficients with varrying length (in this case 3):

```
array: [-1 -1 2]
desired sum: [2]
```

so my ecuation would look like this:

```
-x-y+2z=2
```

output:

```
 result:[-1 1 1]
```

How can this be done in Matlab? I am not sure how I can do recursion.

I was thinking of making something similar to a lock-pick

1 1 1 1

^

Move from here and try all combinations. The values must be `1` or `-1`

Comment: There is an infinite number of solutions for your equation. What are you expecting ?

Comment: Sorry i changed.The possible values can be either 1 or -1.

Comment: Will you always have 3 variables?

Comment: The array is given but its length is not necesarrily 3.The result is given.

Comment: I don't have matlab here, but you can certainly declare a symbolic equation, then use the function `assume` to set all your assumption (x,y,z in [-1,1]), then the function `solve` should be able to give you all the possible answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would generate all possible sequences, then check if they match results. This should be faster and clearer than recursion.

Now, how to generate all possible sequences - grab a hint from binary numbers.

To convert your current number to binary and then array (other steps you require should be clear enough):

```
dec2bin(currentNumber, N); % N is the length of array.
arr = binNum(:) == '1';
matCoeff = -1 + 2 * arr; % This gives 1 on places with 1 and -1 on places with 0.
```